# How to set multiple websites for Facebook App login

Tags: facebook

I have an app server (app.a.com) and a test server (test.a.com). I set "App Domains" as "*.a.com". How do I set "Website with Facebook Login" so that both server will work?

Comment: in your "`App Domains`" just put `a.com`. And have you tried leaving the `Website with Facebook Login` empty (not sure about this!)? if that didn't work, how about just adding `a.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I do this on my site.

In the [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) in the "Basic" tab, set:

`App Domains` to your-domain.com

`Website with Facebook Login` to http://your-domain.com

Then your app URLs will look like this:

http://www.example.com/php_sdk/get_user_feed.php

and

http://test.example.com/php_sdk/get_user_feed.php

Where get_user_feed.php in subdomain `test` is a different file than the one on `www`